# Massively multithreaded writer with Springboot / Hibernate / RabbitMQ

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have the following architecture:

- 3 docker nodes running in a docker swarm
- one rabbitmq server as service running in that swarm
- one process (Proc*N* in the picture) on each node as a consumer
- one process (Proc0 in the picture) acting as a bulk-producer of messages to be consumed

Proc0 creates approximately 150k messages and send them to the rabbitmq-instance, which is used as a stack or queue. Each Proc*N* is listening for messages and processing them. The processing results in an average of 150-250 records which are stored in a database table (IBM DB/2) running on a dedicated host (AIX).

I am using Spring Boot AMQP for message handling and JPA / hibernate for database access.

The rabbitmq configuration is pretty straightforward

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.type=direct
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.consumers-per-queue=15
```

Here is an architectural picture:

[image]

Upon starting the process (that is, starting Proc0 to create the messages), everything looks fine, the throughput (measured by Springboot actuator health and prometheus) raises to a certain point. However: after that certain point, the throughput declines down to a meager fraction of what it was on the start:

[image]

The same picture applies with more/less messages and/or more/less consumers per queue per host.

The target database has an `@Id` column with its generated values coming from a database sequence.

To me, it seems like i suffer a thread starvation of the thread from each proc*N*.

I have a few questions:

- how does hibernate handle the sequence generated id values (of the targettable) in a multithreaded environment?
- Are they sychronized (i suppose so)?
- And if so, would using a database genereated Id help?
- How can i get metrics or measures to pinpoint the cause for the thread starvation?
- Are there "best practices" how to tackle such problems?

Comment: The database is a DB/2 AESE running on a 128GB IBM Power System (8284-22A) running 4 CPU with 24 cores in total (iirc). What specific questions do you have?

Comment: i don't have questions. it sounds like you need to do some learning about databases. also the dba should have tools to measure performance and help you see where the problems are.

Comment: Can't you be more specific? Do you mean that massive parallel writing is the problem here? I doubt that, since i have a similar job in written PL/SQL (~25 parallel threads) and i dont have this effect there.

Comment: i think your thoughts about id generation might not be bad guesses, i've had to use hi-lo tables for that kind of thing. but your dba should be able to a good view of what's going on.